# Get the data of last 7 quarters from database in laravel using created_at value from table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to get last 7 quarters data from database using created_at value from table that you will come to know by seeing my code below.
BTW this code works for days,months and year by replacing quarter to one of this words.While running this code I got following error

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'quarter' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select `client_accounts`.* from `client_accounts`
>   inner join `leads` on `client_accounts`.`clients_id` =
>   `leads`.`clients_id` inner join `associates` on
>   `leads`.`associates_id` = `associates`.`id` where `quarter` =
>   client_accounts.created_at and `associates`.`users_id` = 1) ◀"

```
          for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    {
        $usersquarter[] = ClientAccount::wherequarter('client_accounts.created_at', '=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subQuarter($i)->quarter)
                        ->select('client_accounts.*')
                        ->join('leads', 'client_accounts.clients_id', '=', 'leads.clients_id')
                        ->join('associates', 'leads.associates_id', '=', 'associates.id')
                        ->where('associates.users_id', '=', $associateid)
                        ->get();
    }
```

Comment: A quarter is just three months, no?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes quarter is of three months